# How to covert object array to Array List using for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey I am trying to convert object in array list i tried a lot of but i could not convert here is the code that i tried

const dat1 = [];

```
for (let i = 0; i < topology.length; i++) {
  const data = [data1[i]];

  dat1.push({
    value:data
  });
}
```

Here is the result that i got of `value` .

```
const topology = [
      {
        label: "secondary",
        value: 0.10558737933770979
      },
      {
        label: "unclassified",
        value: 0.07702637029193307
      },
      {
        label: "residential",
        value: 0.05898100977978933
      },
      {
        label: "tertiary",
        value: 0.3012573789201084
      },
      {
        label: "primary",
        value: 0.44342463442819086
      },
      {
        label: "primary_link",
        value: 0.013723227242268547
      },
    ];
```

and Here is the result that i want `value` look like in `Array` form.

```
const topology = [
      {
        label: "secondary",
        value: [0.10558737933770979]
      },
      {
        label: "unclassified",
        value: [0.07702637029193307]
      },
      {
        label: "residential",
        value: [0.05898100977978933]
      },
      {
        label: "tertiary",
        value: [0.3012573789201084]
      },
      {
        label: "primary",
        value: [0.44342463442819086]
      },
      {
        label: "primary_link",
        value: [0.01372322724226854]
      },
    ];
```

Comment: It's unclear what the object and what the output should look like, could you share those with us please?

Comment: I updated @LuísRamalho

Comment: It's still not clear. You want to convert an array of objects into an array of other objects that seem to be clusted by something "large roads", "private roads", ...). What are the criteria for these clusters? How does the algorithm look?

Comment: I think now its clear @fjc

Comment: What you want more to describe?@fjc

Comment: first you cannot push to a constant array const dat1 = [];, declare variables using let or var

Comment: @Vipin Why not? `const` doesn't prevent manipulating the variable, only reassigning.

Comment: I think I got what you mean, please check my answer below and let me know if you have any questions about it

Comment: What is `data1`? Is it supposed to be `topology`? And is `dat1.push` Supposed to be `data1.push`? Also, what is the value of your initial data (either `topology` or `data1`)?

Comment: @Piotr, I've edited my answer with a second snipped built on top of what you had so far. Please let me know if it's clear what the issue was with your original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map the original `topology` and then just return the `value` wrapped in an array, like so:

```js
const topology = [
  {
    label: "secondary",
    value: 0.10558737933770979,
  },
  {
    label: "unclassified",
    value: 0.07702637029193307,
  },
  {
    label: "residential",
    value: 0.05898100977978933,
  },
  {
    label: "tertiary",
    value: 0.3012573789201084,
  },
  {
    label: "primary",
    value: 0.44342463442819086,
  },
  {
    label: "primary_link",
    value: 0.013723227242268547,
  },
];

let result = topology.map(({ label, value }) => ({ label, value: [value] }));

console.log(result);
```

You can also follow your approach, like so:

```
const data1 = [];
for (let i = 0; i < topology.length; i++) {
  const data = [topology[i].value];
  data1.push({
    label: topology[i].label,
    value: data,
  });
}
```

You were very close, just missing getting the value to be wrapped, i.e. you want the "old data", not the current new, so not `[data1[i]]` but `[topology[i].value]` and then adding the label to the new object in `data1` array.

```js
const topology = [
  {
    label: "secondary",
    value: 0.10558737933770979,
  },
  {
    label: "unclassified",
    value: 0.07702637029193307,
  },
  {
    label: "residential",
    value: 0.05898100977978933,
  },
  {
    label: "tertiary",
    value: 0.3012573789201084,
  },
  {
    label: "primary",
    value: 0.44342463442819086,
  },
  {
    label: "primary_link",
    value: 0.013723227242268547,
  },
];

const data1 = [];
for (let i = 0; i < topology.length; i++) {
  const data = [topology[i].value];
  data1.push({
    label: topology[i].label,
    value: data,
  });
}

console.log(data1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
const changed = topology.map(({ label, value }) => ({
  label,
  value: [value]
}));
```

Basically just transforms the original data to wrap the value as an array with a single element.